# Parallel iteration over array with step size greater than 1

Tags: .net-core, f#, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

I'm working on a practice program for doing belief propagation stereo vision.  The relevant aspect of that here is that I have a fairly long array representing every pixel in an image, and want to carry out an operation on every *second* entry in the array at each iteration of a for loop - first one half of the entries, and then at the next iteration the other half (this comes from an optimisation described by Felzenswalb & Huttenlocher in their 2006 paper 'Efficient belief propagation for early vision'.)  So, you could see it as having an outer for loop which runs a number of times, and for each iteration of that loop I iterate over half of the entries in the array.

I would like to parallelise the operation of iterating over the array like this, since I believe it would be thread-safe to do so, and of course potentially faster.  The operation involved updates values inside the data structures representing the neighbouring pixels, which are not themselves used in a given iteration of the outer loop.  Originally I just iterated over the entire array in one go, which meant that it was fairly trivial to carry this out - all I needed to do was put `.Parallel` between `Array` and `.iteri`.  Changing to operating on every second array entry is trickier, however.

To make the change from simply iterating over every entry, I from `Array.iteri (fun i p -> ...` to using `for i in startIndex..2..(ArrayLength - 1) do`, where startIndex is either 1 or 0 depending on which one I used last (controlled by toggling a boolean).  This means though that I can't simply use the really nice `.Parallel` to make things run in parallel.

I haven't been able to find anything specific about how to implement a parallel for loop in .NET which has a step size greater than 1.  The best I could find was [a paragraph in an old MSDN document on parallel programming in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff963552(v=pandp.10)#step-size-other-than-one), but that paragraph only makes a vague statement about transforming an index inside a loop body.  I do not understand what is meant there.

I looked at [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netcore-2.2) and [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netcore-2.2), as well as [creating a custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl?view=netframework-4.8) [partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=netcore-2.2), but none of those seemed to include options for changing the step size.

The other option that occurred to me was to use a sequence expression such as

```
let getOddOrEvenArrayEntries myarray oddOrEven =
    seq {
        let startingIndex =
            if oddOrEven then
                1
            else
                0
        for i in startingIndex..2..(Array.length myarray- 1) do
            yield (i, myarray.[i])
    }
```

and then using `PSeq.iteri` from [ParallelSeq](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/), but I'm not sure whether it will work correctly with .NET Core 2.2.  (Note that, currently at least, I need to know the index of the given element in the array, as it is used as the index into another array during the processing).

How can I go about iterating over every second element of an array in parallel?  I.e. iterating over an array using a step size greater than 1?

Comment: It's usually next-to-impossible to know if one solution is more performant than another without measuring it. (Unless one is O(N) and another is O(N^2), of course, but I'm talking about solutions of the same big-O magnitude). I doubt anyone will be able to give you a good answer unless they've already encountered your exact situation and benchmarked it. In other words, https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet is probably how you'll get your answer.

Comment: @rmunn You make a good point.  There's still the question of how to parallelise a for loop/array iteration that uses a step size other than 1, though, regardless of how performant it may be.  I'll edit the question to focus on that part, rather than what would be performant.

Comment: @Jarak Since you only care about *even* pixels, you could iterate from 0 to `array.Length/2` in `Parallel.For`. Another option is to use PLINQ's [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_ParallelEnumerable_Where__1_System_Linq_ParallelQuery___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) overload that accepts and index and filter out odd positions. This way you parallelize the search too

Comment: @Jarak as for changing the step size, incrementing the index from `0` to `N` by `step` is the same as iterating from `0` to `N/step` and multiplying the index by `step` before using it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Darn good point!  I'm rather embarassed that I didn't think of it myself (I'm pretty sure I have done so in the past).  Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: @Jarak make sure you *do* benchmark your code though. Accessing every second pixel will end up loading *all* the data into the CPU's cache. You'll still process only half the pixels, but you won't get the 4x/8x improvement you expected. If, on the other hand, you perform a different operation inside the loop based on the index (odd/even), you'll only load the data once

Comment: Also in F# using for expression with step size other than 1 or -1 increases overhead alot. Also using other types to iterate over than int. IMHO when you want to iterate with performance it is often better to use tail rec.

Comment: I also encourage measuring performance and compare the parallel performance with the a simple but efficient sequential loop. Sometimes the overhead of the abstractions are so large that the sequential loop end up faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `PSeq.mapi` which provides not only a sequence item as a parameter but also the index of an item.
Here's a small example

```
let res = nums
                |> PSeq.mapi(fun index item -> if index % 2 = 0 then item else item + 1)
```

You can also have a look over this [sampling snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/aN/title/Take-a-sample-of-a-sequence). Just be sure to substitute `Seq` with `PSeq`

Comment: Thanks.  FYI, while looking at the sampling snippet you linked to, I stumbled across [another one](http://www.fssnip.net/1R/title/Take-every-Nth-element-of-sequence) that seems to do much the same thing.